# Approximating a function by integrating it

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, finite-volume-method

I stumbled over this approximization for a flow-map $m:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ in [this paper](https://people.math.sc.edu/wuchen/papers/EMD.pdf), pages 4-5.
The authors approximate the map by integrating it over subsets of its domain. I dont understand, why we can do such a thing to approximate a function.

[image]

[image]

For example let $m(x)=x^2$ and for $\Omega=[0,1]$ let the discretization given by $\{0,h,2h,...,1\}, 1 = Nh, N\in \mathbb{N}$.
If I apply the technique from above, I get that the approximation error can never vanish by just changing the grid.
$$
|m(x_i) -\tilde{m}(x_i)| = |x_i^2 - \int_{x_i}^{x_i+\Delta x}x^2dx| \\ =  |x_i^2 - \frac{1}{3}((x_i+\Delta x)^3 -x_i^3)|\overset{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}{\rightarrow} |x_i^2|
$$

Is there something, that I do not see here?

Comment: $C(x_i + \Delta x,y_i) = \{(x',y')\in \mathbb{R}^2| |x'-x_i-\Delta x| \leq \Delta x/2, |y-y'|\leq \Delta x/2\}$, i.e. the unit ball w.r.t. $||\cdot||_1$ shifted by one halfe step size

Comment: I have added the definition in the text